# Get the string representation of a DOM node

Tags: javascript, string, dom, cross-browser, element

Javascript: I have the DOM representation of a node (element or document) and I'm looking for the string representation of it. E.g.,

```
var el = document.createElement("p");
el.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Test"));
```

should yield:

```
get_string(el) == "<p>Test</p>";
```

I have the strong feeling, that I'm missing something trivially simple, but I just don't find a method that works in IE, FF, Safari and Opera. Therefore, outerHTML is no option.

Comment: With presumably version 11 Firefox also supports outerHTML: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92264

Comment: For now, looks IE, FF, Safari, Chrome, Opera all support outerHTML, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML

Comment: Yes, it has now (since 2009, that is) become a trivial task :)

Comment: Yea, definitely outerHTML

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can create a temporary parent node, and get the innerHTML content of it:

```
var el = document.createElement("p");
el.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Test"));

var tmp = document.createElement("div");
tmp.appendChild(el);
console.log(tmp.innerHTML); // <p>Test</p>
```

**EDIT:** 
Please see answer below about outerHTML. el.outerHTML should be all that is needed.

Comment: Ouch. So simple... Just a little note: If I want the whole document "stringified", I can use the same method with document.documentElement (usecase: AJAX requests). Perhaps you could incorporate that in the answer?

Comment: @Boldewyn: you can append the entire `document.documentElement` into a div? Holy crap....

Comment: Simple, as hell... +1
Too bad documentFragment does not support innerHTML

Comment: This appears to omit the elements' attributes, like `class`. Any way to get those in the output?

Comment: outerHTML is the answer

Comment: I had an array of nodes (from jQuery's parseHTML function), and was able to simply map across them with a function extracting `outerHTML`, and then join the resulting array of strings with no separator. The result was an HTML string equivalent to what I had put in, but containing the subsequent changes I had applied to the nodes.

Comment: Don't forget to clone your `element` before adding it to `tmp` becouse when you add it to `tmp`, it will be removed from `document`.

Comment: This have to be best answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35913488/2179748

Comment: if you want the tag too, outerHTML is the correct answer

Answer (score 61):

What you're looking for is 'outerHTML', but we need a fallback because it's not compatible with old browsers.

```
var getString = (function() {
  var DIV = document.createElement("div");

  if ('outerHTML' in DIV)
    return function(node) {
      return node.outerHTML;
    };

  return function(node) {
    var div = DIV.cloneNode();
    div.appendChild(node.cloneNode(true));
    return div.innerHTML;
  };

})();

// getString(el) == "<p>Test</p>"
```

You'll find my jQuery plugin here: [Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html/20079340#20079340)

Comment: Firefox added `outerHTML` in version 11, after I asked the question. So that wasn't an option back then. I even updated my question with an appropriate comment, if you look closely.

Comment: This right, coz you drop element id's and other attrs if use `innerHtml`

Comment: @SergeyPanfilov: I didn't drop anything because I wrapped the node in an empty div before calling `innerHTML` ; )

Comment: In 2015, I would say this is far and away the best answer.

Comment: Yeah, as of today, only very old (IE>10,Safari >7, truly ancient FF, Chrome) and/or obscure browsers (Opera Mini) do not support the `outerHTML` attribute. See also http://caniuse.com/#feat=xml-serializer

Comment: Simply `document.documentElement.outerHTML;` if you don't care about old browsers.

Answer (score 27):

I dont think you need any complicated script for this. Just use

```
get_string=(el)=>el.outerHTML;
```

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: Today we can simply use outerHTML

Answer (score 22):

Under FF you can use the `XMLSerializer` object to serialize XML into a string.  IE gives you an `xml` property of a node.  So you can do the following:

```
function xml2string(node) {
   if (typeof(XMLSerializer) !== 'undefined') {
      var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
      return serializer.serializeToString(node);
   } else if (node.xml) {
      return node.xml;
   }
}
```

Comment: FYI `.xml` doesn't work on DOM nodes (as in nodes in the current page). It only works on XML DOM document nodes.

Comment: And conversely, `outerHTML` doesn't work on XML DOM document nodes. It only works on DOM nodes (as in nodes in the current page). Good consistency there I'd say.

Answer (score 11):

Use Element#outerHTML:

```
var el = document.createElement("p");
el.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Test"));

console.log(el.outerHTML);
```

It can also be used to write DOM elements. From Mozilla's documentation:

> The outerHTML attribute of the element DOM interface gets the serialized HTML fragment describing the element including its descendants. It can be set to replace the element with nodes parsed from the given string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(element);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that is exactly what Bryan Kale suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use **outerHTML** property over the element. It will return what you desire.

Let's create a function named **`get_string(element)`**

```js
var el = document.createElement("p");
el.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Test"));

function get_string(element) {
 console.log(element.outerHTML);
}

get_string(el); // your desired output
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use element.outerHTML to get full representation of element, including outer tags and attributes.

Answer (score 2):

If your element has parent

```
element.parentElement.innerHTML
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately that was already suggested, but the answerer deleted the answer. The problem is, that the parent might contain a lot _more_ markup than wanted. Think of outerHTML for a single `<li>` in a list.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that for my use-cases I don't always want the entire outerHTML. Many nodes just have too many children to show.

Here's a function (minimally tested in Chrome):

```
/**
 * Stringifies a DOM node.
 * @param {Object} el - A DOM node.
 * @param {Number} truncate - How much to truncate innerHTML of element.
 * @returns {String} - A stringified node with attributes
 *                     retained.
 */
function stringifyEl(el, truncate) {
    var truncateLen = truncate || 50;
    var outerHTML = el.outerHTML;
    var ret = outerHTML;
    ret = ret.substring(0, truncateLen);

    // If we've truncated, add an elipsis.
    if (outerHTML.length > truncateLen) {
      ret += "...";
    }
    return ret;
}
```

https://gist.github.com/kahunacohen/467f5cc259b5d4a85eb201518dcb15ec

Answer (score 0):

I have wasted a lot of time figuring out what is wrong when I iterate through DOMElements with the code in the accepted answer. This is what worked for me, otherwise every second element disappears from the document:

```
_getGpxString: function(node) {
          clone = node.cloneNode(true);
          var tmp = document.createElement("div");
          tmp.appendChild(clone);
          return tmp.innerHTML;
        },
```

Comment: I don't go out on a limb, when I suppose, that you have a different problem here. Note, that the above solution _removes_ the original element from the DOM. So, when you use a _live_ collection like `document.getElementsByTagName()`, that collection will change mid-`for`-loop, hence the skipping of every second element.

Answer (score 0):

While `outerHTML` is usually the answer, for `Attr` and `Text`(Child classes of the `Node` interface), there are other properties:

```js
(<Element>x).outerHTML
(<Text>x).data
(<Attr>x).value;
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node for more types of Nodes such as `DocumentFragment` and `Comment`

Answer (score -2):

if using react:

```
const html = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]).outerHTML;
```

Comment: `.outerHTML` is not React-specific; it is a DOM standard. Check out @Rich Apodaca’s answer.

Comment: yes... the point of interest (if using react) on my answer was `reactdom.findDOMNode()`... , not the `.outerHTML`, but thanks for the position.