# How to make temporary HTML and clone data to it?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, report

I got a table in my HTML and I want to generate new temporary HTML only with this table. How can I achieve it with HTML or JavaScript?

Comment: if someone is interested in results than:
Table cloning used from nemo's answer, and for temporary HTML creation used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750815/get-the-string-representation-of-a-dom-node) answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var tempTable = document.getElementById("myTableId").cloneNode(true);
```

Where myTableId is the id of the table you want to clone.
Then you can append your tempTable wherever you want(using [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.appendChild) )

Comment: Thanks, definitely will use this, now I have to figure out how to make temporary HTML