# can we pass DOM elements using postMessage?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, postmessage

I have 2 iframes on a page and I am trying to pass DOM element from one iframe to another using postMessage. But chrome keep giving me error:

> "DataCloneError: An object could not be cloned. "

Is there a way around this issue ?

Answer (score 8):

According to the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-messaging.html#posting-messages), you can't send DOM nodes and it will throw an error.

> Messages can be structured objects, e.g. nested objects and arrays, can contain JavaScript values (strings, numbers, Date objects, etc), and can contain certain data objects such as File Blob, FileList, and ArrayBuffer objects.

Answer (score 1):

You might try with **innerHTML**, which "*gets or sets the HTML or XML markup contained within the element.*" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

With innerHTML you can pass element's content as a string, and then, in the other iframe, insert that content, again with innerHTML.

In this answer there is a simple way to get the innerHTML content of a node:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1750860/1401341

You won't get events attached to the element, but in some cases this method could be enough.