# How can you evaluate JSF tags inside a JavaScript string?

Tags: javascript, jsf

For example in the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

    var str = '<h:graphicImage library="images" name="foo.png" />'

//]]>
</script>
```

I want `str` to contain the `<img ...>` tag with the correct source etc.

Comment: Why? What's the real task?

Answer (score 0):

Jsf tags are evaluated on a server, not in browser. Javascript is always evaluated in browser. So write

```
<h:form id="formid">
   <h:panelGroup id="groupId" style="display: none;">
       <h:graphicImage library="images" name="foo.png" id="imageId"  />
   </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var node=document.getElementById("formid:groupId");
var str = node.innerHtml;
//]]>
</script>
```

somewhere in your .xhtml.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1750860/2023524